# How do I remove a value that I define if a row returns NULL within a CONCAT function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to remove a value that I define if a row returns NULL within a CONCAT function.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about it..

```
CONCAT('Floor:', ' ', l1.floor, ' ', 'Unit:', ' ', l1.unit_number, ' ', 'Buzzer:', ' ', l1.buzzer) as R_ADDRESS2,
```

I'd like each instance of values to be blank if the row is NULL.
So if `l1.floor` returns NULL then `'Floor:', ' '` don't showup in the column for `R_ADDRESS2` either.
Same for `l1.unit_number`, and `l1.buzzer`.

How would I do that?

EDIT:
Here is how it is showing up currently:

```
r_address2

Floor: 10 Unit: Buzzer:
Floor: 2 Unit: 200 Buzzer:
Floor: Unit: Buzzer:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',
          ('Floor: ' || l1.floor),
          ('Unit: ' || l1.unit_number),
          ('Buzzer: ' || l1.buzzer)
         ) as R_ADDRESS2,
```

`||` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.  However, `CONCAT_WS()` ignores `NULL` arguments, so the combination does what you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=09316c42167da4ca985d4ef37e73fd75) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: "*CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL*" - not true. https://rextester.com/FHQ49608 - this is only true for the concat operator `||`

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Added the code exactly as shown, but am still seeing `Floor:` `Unit:` and `:Buzzer` show up. I've added an edit to my question to show what it looks like with `CONCAT_WS`.

Comment: That would be true for MySQL. Just use `||` instead of CONCAT.

Comment: @Tom . . . I either tested it on MySQL or used `||` for testing.

Answer (score 1):

`concat` function ignores `null`s, "usual" concatenation does't. Use both of them.

```
CONCAT('Floor: ' + l1.floor + ' ', -- or cast(l1.floor as varchar) if it is int
    'Unit: ' + l1.unit_number + ' ', 
    'Buzzer: ' + l1.buzzer) as R_ADDRESS2,
```